# Unable to Update Static Variable (easy fix?) (Java)

Tags: java, object, static

I am having an issue getting my variable 'totalsales' to return a value other than zero... I would imagine I'm not updating the static variable properly but I cannot figure it out... Hopefully someone can help me out!

IceCreamTruck.java:

```
public class IceCreamTruck {
    private static double price; //price for ice cream cones
    private String truckID;
    private int pertrucksnumsold; //for the number of ice creams sold per day per truck
    private double pertrucksales=price*pertrucksnumsold; //for the number of ice creams sold as a dollar amount
    private static int totalnumsold; //for the number of ice creams sold per day for all trucks
    private static double totalsales=totalnumsold*price;
    private static int numTrucks; //this will keep track of the total number of trucks to calculate averages etc


    public IceCreamTruck(String id,int s){ //this also serves as the constructor for truckID
        truckID=id;
        pertrucksnumsold=s;
        totalnumsold+=s;
        numTrucks ++;
    }

    public static void setPrice(double p){
        price=p;
    }

    public static int returnNumSold(){
        return totalnumsold;
    }

    public static double avgSales(){ //average number of ice creams sold per truck
        return totalsales/numTrucks;
    }

    public void Sale(){ //used to keep track of all ice cream sales per truck
        pertrucksnumsold ++;
        totalnumsold ++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Ice-cream sold by "+truckID+": "+ pertrucksnumsold+" Total sales for "+truckID+": "+pertrucksales;
    }

    public static double totalSales(){ //returns total sales by all trucks
        return totalsales;
    }




}
```

Above is the object and Im trying to use it in this main method in another class named IceCreamTruckDemo.java:

```
public class IceCreamTruckDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        IceCreamTruck t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
        IceCreamTruck.setPrice(2.00);

        t1=new IceCreamTruck("Truck 1",5); //truck id,num of ic sold per truck
        t2=new IceCreamTruck("Truck 2",4);
        t3=new IceCreamTruck("Truck 3",3);
        t4=new IceCreamTruck("Truck 4",2);
        t5=new IceCreamTruck("Truck 5",1);

        System.out.println("Ice cream sales by truck:");
        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
        System.out.println(t3);
        System.out.println(t4);
        System.out.println(t5);

        System.out.println("Total ice-cream sold by all trucks "+IceCreamTruck.returnNumSold());
        System.out.println("Total sales: $"+IceCreamTruck.totalSales());
        System.out.println("Average sales per truck: $"+IceCreamTruck.avgSales());


    }
}
```

This is all I can get to output...

```
Ice cream sales by truck:
Ice-cream sold by Truck 1: 5 Total sales for Truck 1: 0.0
Ice-cream sold by Truck 2: 4 Total sales for Truck 2: 0.0
Ice-cream sold by Truck 3: 3 Total sales for Truck 3: 0.0
Ice-cream sold by Truck 4: 2 Total sales for Truck 4: 0.0
Ice-cream sold by Truck 5: 1 Total sales for Truck 5: 0.0
Total ice-cream sold by all trucks 15
Total sales: $0.0
Average sales per truck: $0.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you figured out one solution to this in your comment and wanted to know a better way. You can call those two methods you created in the constructor. Also, nice job on finding out the initial solution for yourself.

```
  public IceCreamTruck(String id,int s){ //this also serves as the constructor for truckID
    truckID=id;
    pertrucksnumsold=s;
    totalnumsold+=s;
    numTrucks ++;
    this.setTotalSales();
    this.setPerTruckSales();


}
```

edit: just for anyone else who comes across this thread,  here are the two setter methods he had created:

```
public static void setTotalSales() {totalsales=totalnumsoldprice;} 
public void setPerTruckSales(){pertrucksales=pricepertrucksnumsold;}
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks, I had a revelation.. I woke up in the middle of the night and figured this exact thing would infact work! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
private static double price;
private static int totalnumsold;
private static double totalsales=totalnumsold*price;
```

These variables are initialized in the order they appear as they are all static fields ([JLS 8.3.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.1)). As you have not specified the value for price and totalnumsold and they are both static fields, they will be assigned their *default value*. For a double the default value is 0.0d while an int has the default value of 0 ([JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)).

So, `price = 0.0d`, `totlanumsold = 0` hence `totalsales = 0 * 0.0d = 0.0d`. Total sales is **never** changed again, so it remains as 0.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a homework problem, so no code.  A pointer, however:

You have defined a class-static variable called `totalsales`, but I don't see where your code updates or assigns to it.  For `totalsales` to change, it has to be modified.  Where would you do that?

Comment: Your feeling is right and I appreciate that you didn't just throw some code here for me to copy because I really just want to understand what Im doing incorrectly. Why can't I just update it in the IceCreamTruck class? Must I create a new setter to change totalsales and call it in the main method?

Comment: "Doing incorrectly": a couple of things.  I'll leave those to a further date for your study, but answering your questions here: You *can* update it in the ICT class.  That's one reason for setters.  But must you create a setter?  No, you already have one.  (Hint: what does `Sale()` do?)

Comment: I created 2 methods in the ICT class:

public static void setTotalSales(){totalsales=totalnumsold*price;}

    public void setPerTruckSales(){pertrucksales=price*pertrucksnumsold;}

this works but i have to call set per truck sales for each instance of the truck... is there a better way? 

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Yes, there is a better way, but don't sell yourself short here.  Own the good feeling of solving this particular problem.  Meanwhile, if you're ready for the next step, I would ask how you would write/rewrite this code so that it completely avoids any global state (i.e., in this case, no static variables).

Comment: There was a note on the assignment that there is infact a better way to keep track of the running total without the use of a static variable and we will get to that method. I got it working as required for the assignment. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of Icecream truck before you can set your price.